# Is ADAL used in ASP Net Core with OpenIdConnect

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, adal

I have an old web application in ASP .Net core 2.1 which is authenticating users against Azure AD.

Give the fact that Microsoft will end support for ADAL, recommending to move to MSAL, I need to figure out if my application will still work, and if is using ADAL

Does anyone know if ADAL is used in .AddOpenIdConnect Version=2.1.2.0 ?

```
// Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect, Version=2.1.2.0

              .AddOpenIdConnect(option =>
              {
                  option.ClientId = ClientId;
                  option.ClientSecret = ClientSecret;
                  option.Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Tenant}";
                  option.Resource = "https://graph.windows.net";
                  option.SignedOutRedirectUri = SignedOutRedirectUri;
                  option.CorrelationCookie.Name = "cookie name";
                  option.NonceCookie.Name = "nonce name";
                  option.NonceCookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;                
                  option.CorrelationCookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                  ....
              }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your resource URL `https://graph.windows.net` points to the token endpoint for **Azure AD Graph (ADAL)**

The token endpoint for **MS Graph (MSAL)** is `https://graph.microsoft.com`

Here is extended information about [planning your app migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/migrate-azure-ad-graph-planning-checklist)